# How to edit email generated by "Send Invite Link" POST request

Tags: java, post, http-post, onelogin

I am try to figure out how to customize the email that is sent by a "Send Invite Link" POST request to OneLoggin.

https://developers.onelogin.com/api-docs/1/invite-links/send-invite-link

I am trying to edit who the email is from and the subject.

https://dbu.onelogin.com/branding/#custom-invite
Here you can edit the invite without password email body which is the one I am sending but how would you edit the subject or who is shown as the sender?

Any ideas?

Comment: Do you tried anything already? Provide some code snippets or requests you tried please...

Comment: Your question is very broad. What about the email do you want to customize? The sender? The recipient? The body of the email? The subject? Please provide a sample of code that you have tried and a more focused description of what you are trying to do.

Comment: Thanks for the comments, I updated the questions. @niall_atlasidentity answer helped a little as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can't. The email is configured in the Onelogin console, and that API only triggers what has been previously configured.

In the console Settings -> Branding -> Invites